# Unchecked assignment warning on method with identical return type

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea

In the class `Grafo` I have the following method:

`public List<Vertice<T>> getVertices()`

and then in the subclass `GrafoGOT` I'm trying to do the following assignment:

`List<Vertice> vertices = this.getVertices();`

but i'm somehow getting an `Unchecked assignment` error in Intellij IDEA.

Why am I getting an error and what should I do to remove it?

Comment: `List<Vertice<T>>` is not the same as `List<Vertice>` -- note the missing `<T>` in the second declaration.

Comment: `List<Vertice<String>>` ?

Comment: @JimGarrison I miss that. :(

Comment: `Vertice<T>` is a correct generic. `Vertice` is a *raw* generic. Do not use *raw* generics. See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5221149)

Comment: @JimGarrison you're right, I omitted that because I had messed up the class declaration and it didn't know about T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed assignment statement to

```
List<Vertice<T>> vertices = this.getVertices();
```

`Vertice` is a generic type.

If GrafoGOT class declaration is not generic like

```
class GrafoGOT extends Grafo<String> {}
```

then assignment statement will change to

```
List<Vertice<String>> vertices = this.getVertices();
```

Comment: Depends if the subclass knows about T.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Huh? When both classes use the *same* class Vertex, then of course that class is generic. And leaving out the generic parm turns it into a raw parm.

Comment: What Thorbon is saying: you need that generic type parameter for Vertice, true. It could be T (if the subclass knows that T), otherwise it would have to be a specific class, (like when T in the Subclass is String or whatever)